# заменить значение заголовков pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм с заголовками

```
Клиент  КАТЕГОРИЯ   BU  вес кор.    Код товар   Склад отгрузки  Ед. изм.    Наименование    Вид прогноза    40  40.1    40.2    40.3    40.4    40.5    40.6
```

Нужно данные заголовка заменить на вторую строку этого датафрейма
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать

Comment: можете привести в вопросе вывод команды: `print(df.columns)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Либо при чтении файла через read_csv или read_table задать параметр `header = 1`.